# Apply htaccess rules for all cases except a few

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want every access to:

`www.example.com/demo/action.html`

to redirect to

`www.example.com/demo/?section=action`

Being `action` the variable that changes. 
But, I do not want to apply that rule in a couple of cases, lets say:

```
www.example.com/demo/mypage1.html
www.example.com/demo/mypage2.html
```

For those cases I want them to load the real html pages `mypage1.html` and `mypage2.html`.

At the moment I have like 20 rules for all possible `action` variables. But as it doesn't seem to be ideal in terms of performance, I would rather have just the 2 special cases and a single rule for all the other cases.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/removeUser.html$ demo/?section=removeUser [QSA]
RewriteRule ^demo/addUser.html$ demo/?section=addUser[QSA]
RewriteRule ^demo/addUser.html$ demo/?section=editUser[QSA]
RewriteRule ^demo/addUser.html$ demo/?section=comment[QSA]
... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep exception at the top and then a generic rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^demo/(?:mypage1|mypage2)\.html$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^demo/([\w-]+)\.html$ demo/?section=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

This assumes that `demo/` directory has no .htaccess inside.

However if you are just looking at excluding all existing files from this rewrite then you just a single rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^demo/([\w-]+)\.html$ demo/?section=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I have 10 or 12 special cases? That will be a long line. Would that be the best way of doing so? 
Or better to define a rule per special case?

Comment: Even for 11/12 special cases keeping them all in a single rule is fine. But if you have too many special cases then you can break down in multiple exception rules.

Comment: I was wondering... couldn't I use something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` so I can save myself from writting the rewrite rule for the files that do exist ? The "special cases" ?

Comment: Do you only want to exclude all **existing files**? In other words does it mean `demo/mypage1.html`, `demo/mypage2.html` are existing files but `demo/action.html` is not?

Comment: Exactly :) That's it.

Comment: ok this was not clearly mentioned in question But if that's the case then it is quite simple. Remove exception rule and add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` before rewrite rule.